# I have a variable in php called as id. I want to use it as a table name.This code is not creating the table in php myadmin

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, dynamic

I have to use the $id variable as table name but it is not working.

```
       $sql1="CREATE TABLE $id(
              amt_to_be_paid INT(6),
              no_of_days_req INT(2),
              proposal TEXT NOT NULL,
              channel_link VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
              )";
```

Comment: spare comma at end of last column definition. voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have the full control on the $id variable and is not coming from user input.

You need to concatenate your $id variable to the query string, as following:

```
   $sql1="CREATE TABLE " . $id . "(
          amt_to_be_paid INT(6),
          no_of_days_req INT(2),
          proposal TEXT NOT NULL,
          channel_link VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          )";
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer for a detailed review of how to achieve this : [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)